# In which order does ffprobe give you frame information? Decode or Presentation order?

Tags: ffmpeg

When running a command like:

**ffprobe -show_frames input.ts**

I have been previously told that this shows the frames in PRESENTATION order, but recently have been confused by comments maybe hinting that its the other way around. I want to clear up any confusion. Please can anyone tell me if its in presentation order or decode order?

My thoughts are that they are definitely in PRESENTATION order because I find the sequence to  be I,B,B,P instead of I,P,B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-show_frames` is in presentation order. `-show_packets` is in storage or decoding order.